# Find all substring contain a keyword

Tags: java, substring

I want to `find all the substring` of one String that `contains a key word`.

Ex: "This is the `keyword` in the string".

Output: the keyword, this is the keyword, the keyword in the string, is the keyword in ....

I am think of finding all the substrings first then try to filter one by one. But I think that would be very bad solution.

Could you please give me some advice to do that!. Thank you very much.

I have edited to just find the sequence of tokens.

Comment: Find the substrings of what?

Comment: Do you understand that if there is keyword in a string, it might be a part of many substrings. Please re-structure your question to explain what you actually want. Also, better to provide the code that you tried.

Comment: what have you tried? did you try using a regex? more info is needed to see what's not working or what need improving... thx

Comment: This sounds like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include some examples, e.g. "For the string 'abcd' and keyword 'bc', the results should be 'abc', 'abcd', 'bc', 'bcd'." Also, if you're looking for an algorithm, it might be best to specify that.

Comment: `finding all the substrings`:  **O(n^2)**

Comment: or, if you absolutely must do everything from scratch, you should use a [DFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton)

Comment: One way to reduce the execution time would be to only find all substrings whose lengths are equal to or greater than the length of the keyword.

Comment: I am so sorry for my bad question. But the example is what I want to do.

Comment: Can I reduce the time complexity lower than o(n^2) by using suffix tree ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String str = "abcdefkeybncv...";
String key = "key";
int index = str.indexOf(key);
ArrayList<String> sub = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= str.length() - i; j++) {
        String s = str.substring(i, i+j);
        if(s.indexOf(key) >= 0){
            sub.add(s);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(sub);
```

Output for the code above:

```
[abcdefkey, abcdefkeyb, abcdefkeybn, abcdefkeybnc, abcdefkeybncv, abcdefkeybncv., abcdefkeybncv.., abcdefkeybncv..., bcdefkey, bcdefkeyb, bcdefkeybn, bcdefkeybnc, bcdefkeybncv, bcdefkeybncv., bcdefkeybncv.., bcdefkeybncv..., cdefkey, cdefkeyb, cdefkeybn, cdefkeybnc, cdefkeybncv, cdefkeybncv., cdefkeybncv.., cdefkeybncv..., defkey, defkeyb, defkeybn, defkeybnc, defkeybncv, defkeybncv., defkeybncv.., defkeybncv..., efkey, efkeyb, efkeybn, efkeybnc, efkeybncv, efkeybncv., efkeybncv.., efkeybncv..., fkey, fkeyb, fkeybn, fkeybnc, fkeybncv, fkeybncv., fkeybncv.., fkeybncv..., key, keyb, keybn, keybnc, keybncv, keybncv., keybncv.., keybncv...]
```

Comment: Yes,It has O(n^2) time complexity

Comment: ok, Thank you very much. But can I reduce the time complexity by using suffix tree ?

Comment: There are n^2 substrings of the given string so I think it cannot be faster than that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build suffix array: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array
2. Use binary search to find your substring there
3. Move up and down from this point in suffix array while suffixes starts with substring

Comment: So how about the time complexity?